Question about proof regarding holomorphic maps between Riemann surfaces
So in our lecture notes, we have this proof;

My question is, why the discussion on accumulation points? It seems to me like no part of this proof required any notion of accumulation points. Even the final few sentences make little sense to me, if the function is locally constant on a connected topological space then it should be globally constant anyway. Maybe there is some part of this proof that requires a property of accumulation points? If someone could just help explain why the accumulation points are needed or why the last few sentences even make sense at all, that would greatly help! Thanks

The existence of accumulation points is what forces the function to be constant. To see this, consider the map $\exp(z)$ between $\mathbb C$ and itself. Then $\exp^{-1}(1)$ is an infinite set, but since it  does not have any accumulation point, the function can be $0$ an infinite number of times without being constant

The part that actually needs the existence of accumulation points is this: "so $\phi(a)$ is a non-isolated zero of $h$ and this implies that $h$ must be identically zero". This appeal to the identity principle requires that $\phi(a)$ be an accumulation point (which is equivalent to being a nonisolated zero)

@Pelota okay thank you so much, there was no mention of the identity principle anywhere in the notes so I just assumed that "holomorphic function has non-isolated zeros" implied "function is constant" as a theorem of complex analysis I may not have seen before. I'm still a bit confused on the application to the accumulation set in the last paragraph though. It's obviously clear why A is closed but why is A also open? and why does A=S imply f is constant? Thanks again

Concerning accumulation points: if we didn't have any accumulation points, the theorem would be wrong. As a counterexample, take $f:\mathbb C\to \mathbb C, z\mapsto e^z$, $c=1$. In particular, the piece of the proof that breaks down is the fact that $\phi(a)$ is not necessarily a non-isolated zero anymore, hence $h$ does not have to be constant.
Concerning the proof of openedness of $A:$ since $x$ being an accumulation point of $f^{-1}(c)$ proves that $f$ is constant in a nbhd of $x$, call it $U_x$. Since $f$ is constant in $U_x$, it follows that all of $U_x$ is contained in $f^{-1}(c)$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $U_x$ is homeomorphic to the open unit disk, hence all of its points are accumulation points of $f^{-1}(c)$, which implies $U_x\subset A$. It follows that $A$ is open.
Finally, here is why $A=S$ implies $f$ is constant: by definition $A\subset f^{-1}(c)$, hence $S=f^{-1}(c)$, which implies $f$ is constant.

Okay thanks. It appears I was deeply misunderstanding what an accumulation point was. I think I assumed it was akin to the boundary, however it is more like the closure of a set (in fact I think some people define the accumulation set to be the closure minus isolated points). This helps a lot, appreciate it
